# What is the correct way to incrementally add something to an array in blazor, without re-rendering the whole array?

Tags: blazor

In blazor, I am currently rendering a list :

```
List<string> stuffs = Recieve_Stuffs();
foreach(var stuff in stuffs)
{
  @stuff
}
```

Now if I am adding more thingy to stuffs, is blazor going to re-render all the elements that never changed? is it possible that we can have some sort of mechanism or structures that we can just add one thing to the stack to render it without touching other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@key` helps the render engine know what components need updating. It needs to be placed on the outer html element within the loop.

```
List<string> stuffs = Recieve_Stuffs();
foreach(var stuff in stuffs)
{
  <div @key="stuff.UniqueIdentifier" >
      @stuff
  </div>
}
```

Use [@key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#use-key-to-control-the-preservation-of-elements-and-components-1) to control the preservation of elements and components...

Comment: Thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

Generally no. There is no way in which blazor can know if the members of the other objects in the list have mutated.
If you must, there are two ways, one described by Brian Parker above.
The other is setting `ShouldRender() => false;` in the component that is receiving the list item ('stuff' in your case)
This ensures that the component is rendered only once. You can add some state dependent logic instead of permanently setting it to false.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/rendering?view=aspnetcore-5.0#suppress-ui-refreshing-shouldrender-1

Comment: Thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

The `Renderer` will re-iterate through the list to produce an updated `RenderTree`.

If the only difference between the new RenderTree and the old one is one or more elements added to the end, then only those changes to the `RenderTree` DOM will get passed to the actual Browser DOM.

However, if you start changing the order of things in the list, such as adding a new item to the beginning, then potentially the whole list gets re-rendered.  Adding an @key won't change this.  With the @key Blazor has a way to track all the individual elements/components in the `RenderTree`, and preserve say focus, but the new DOM will differ from the old one, and the full set of changes will get passed to the Browser DOM.

Comment: Thanks for answering

Comment: your answer is actually closer to what I was looking for

Comment: but the guy who mentioned @key in the first place seems to have an answer that's straight forward for SEO and the question

Comment: NP - This answer was just to add a little more info about the render process.